# Track memory-consumption of a part of a program for caching

Tags: c++, templates, caching, memory-management, allocator

I´m looking for an approach to keep track of memory-consumption from a part of my program. What I´m trying to achieve in the actual use-case is to write a cache-class with an upper size limit. Since the cached data is a rather complex hierarchy of some nested classes adding a `getSize()` methods to all this classes should be possible but probably a bad option performance-wise. So far my approach was trying to utilize a custom allocator for the cached classes. Although this is also not an overly elegant solution it would properly track the used memory. But it also requires the classes to be templated, what is breaking the compatibility with non-cached instances. Consider:

```
std::string foo;
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > bar( "text" );
foo = bar; // this will not work
```

Reorganizing the data to some layout that might fit better into a caching mechanism (let´s say some arrays) probably also is not a good option, as it would require (besides a rewrite of most code) additional steps to assemble the data again when requested from the cache, what would mean a performance penalty from caching.

I would be grateful for any advice and looking forward to learn about your thoughts on this.

---

```
#include <string>

namespace
{

    template <class T>
    class CountAlloc : public MemUsage
    {
    public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;

        CountAlloc(){}
        T* allocate( size_t n, const void* = 0 )
        {
            n *= sizeof( T );
            sum() += n;
            std::cout << "+ " << n << " = " << sum() << std::endl;
            return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(n));
        }

        void deallocate( T* const p, std::size_t const n )
        {
            if( p )
            {
                sum() -= n * sizeof( T );
                ::operator delete(p);
                std::cout << "- " << n * sizeof( T ) << " = " << sum() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        T* address( T& x ) const { return &x; }
        T const* address( T const& x ) const { return &x; }
        CountAlloc<T>& operator=( const CountAlloc& ) { return *this; }
        void construct( T* p, const T& val ) { new ((T*)p) T( val ); }
        void destroy( T* p ) { p->~T(); }
        size_type max_size() const { return size_t( -1 ); }
        template <class U>
        struct rebind
        {
            typedef CountAlloc<U> other;
        };

        template <class U>
        CountAlloc( const CountAlloc<U>& other )
        {
        }

        template <class U>
        CountAlloc<T>& operator=( CountAlloc<U> const& other )
        {
            return *this;
        }
    };
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::string foo;
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CountAlloc<char> > bar( "text" );
    foo = bar; // this is not working
}
```

Comment: Hi @liliscent,
in reply to your request I added a full example. Although I honestly don't think it gains anything through this. Maybe I make not clear enough that my question not about why `foo = bar;` is not working. That´s pretty obvious. But rather how to approach the problem of tracking memory usage from some instances or a particular call stack in general. So the example code should not matter too much. If you still should miss any MCVE requirements please point out what information you need exactly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Software Engineering

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, could you pleas explain why you consider this question being off-topic? From my point of view the concepts related to the question like interaction of templates and allocators are quite specific to C++. Also I think that the use-case I outlined is _a specific programming problem_ as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. So I can not understand why this topic should be misplaced as a C++ programming problem.